# Sorting array in VB without using Sort Function

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a sorting program where it takes inputs into an array. I already made Min, Max, and Average. Now I need to do Median, Mode and Sorting (Max to Min, and Min to Max).

Here's the code I got for sorting [UPDATED New Code]

```
       RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(" ", ",")


    marks = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(New String() {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Label3.Text = Nothing

    Dim z As Integer = marks.Length - 1
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim TEMP As Integer

    For X = 1 To z
        For y = 1 To (z - 1)

            If marks(y) > marks(y + 1) Then
                TEMP = marks(y)
                marks(y) = marks(y + 1)
                marks(y + 1) = TEMP

            End If
            Label3.Text = Label3.Text & vbCrLf & marks(y)
        Next y


    Next X
```

Comment: Why can't you use [`Array.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: The task is to make a sort function ..

Comment: See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: "To make a sort function": So this is a school assignment?

Comment: Gosh, I haven't written a bubble sort for years. Takes me back a bit. :-)

Comment: Looks like i'm going to have to code a Bubble Sort ... I'll get to work and report back with what I did. Thanks @Teejay

Comment: It looks like a Selection Sort would be easier .. Any tips on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Selection Sort algorithm from **Wikipedia** converted to VB.net

```
Public Shared Function Sort(ByVal a As Int32()) As Int32()
    Dim n As Int32 = a.Length ' a(n-1) is the last element
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim iMin As Integer

    ' Advance the position through the entire array 
    ' we could do "from j = 0 to n-2" (that is "for j < n-1")
    ' because single element is also min element
    For j = 0 To n - 2
        ' Find the min element in the unsorted a[j .. n-1] 

        ' Assume the min is the first element 
        iMin = j
        ' Test against elements after j to find the smallest 
        For i = j + 1 To n - 1
            ' If this element is less, then it is the new minimum 
            If a(i) < a(iMin) Then
                ' Found new minimum, remember its index 
                iMin = i
            End If
        Next

        ' iMin is the index of the minimum element,
        ' swap it with the current position 
        If iMin <> j Then
            Dim tmp As Int32 = a(j)
            a(j) = a(iMin)
            a(iMin) = tmp
        End If
    Next

    Return a
End Function
```

Reversing it to do a descending sort should not be difficult, once you've fully understood the above.

Comment: Thanks @Teejay , i'm working on applying & understanding the code you provided .. Just a question : would the code I wrote above not work? It seems logically like it should..

Comment: @Ds.109 I tested it and it seems to work, but it prints a lot of output, you need to consider only the last series.

Comment: For me it only prints about 20 numbers.. I.e. Input{4 1 2 8 5} -- Output after sort {1 2 5 0 1 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0} ... so it's kind of working, kind of not.

Comment: I found out that your code strips out the first number in the passed array, plus the greatest number in the array passed. For example: giving {6, 5, 8, 3, 14, 1, 24, 9, 7} it prints {1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 14} stripping out 6 (the first) and 24 (the greatest).

Comment: Ok, I redid the code you provided (so that when I did it I understood it) and it works perfectly .. I'm also going to try to get my original code to work just to see if I can :) .. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like `Sort`, you can use `OrderBy`. LINQ also allows you to calculate `Min`, `Max` and `Average` directly, so you don't need to reinvent the wheel. See this article for more information:

[Using LINQ to Calculate Basic Statistics](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42492/Using-LINQ-to-Calculate-Basic-Statistics)

(includes code for Variance, StandardDeviation, Median, Mode etc.)

Note: The code is C#, but it can be easily converted to VB.NET, since both are .NET languages.

Comment: He said: "The task is to make a sort function .. "

Comment: @Teejay: homework task... okay. Sorry then. I will leave the answer here, in case anybody needs to implement statistical functions with minimum development effort, i.e. for a business need.

Answer (score 0):

To sort a multidimensional array, you can use exactly the same procedure as for sorting a single dimension array.

You loop through the array, and if two adjacent members are in the wrong order, then you swop them around.

Imagine you have a multi-dimension array such as

```
Dim Array(12, 4) String
```

So, suppose you want to order the array by the last column for example.

```
For index1 = 0 to Array.length - 1
For index2 = 0 to Array.length - 2
If Array(index2, 4) > Array(index2 + 1, 4) Then

// this sorts the last column

Temp4 = Array(index2, 4)
Array(index2, 4) = Array(index2 + 1, 4) 
Array(index2 + 1, 4) = Temp4

// and we repeat this swopping pattern for each of the other columns, so they are all sorted in  the same way

Temp3 = Array(index2, 3)
Array(index2, 3) = Array(index2 + 1, 3) 
Array(index2 + 1, 3) = Temp3

Temp2 = Array(index2, 2)
Array(index2, 2) = Array(index2 + 1, 2) 
Array(index2 + 1, 2) = Temp2

Temp1 = Array(index2, 1)
Array(index2, 1) = Array(index2 + 1, 1) 
Array(index2 + 1, 1) = Temp1

Temp0 = Array(index2, 0)
Array(index2, 0) = Array(index2 + 1, 0) 
Array(index2 + 1, 0) = Temp0

Next
Next
```

So now all the columns are sorted by the last column.

You might be wondering how you can sort if 4 columns are strings and one column is a number, and suppose you want to sort by the number column.

You could do this

```
For index1 = 0 to Array.length - 1
For index2 = 0 to Array.length - 2
If CSng(Array(index2, 4)) > CSng(Array(index2 + 1, 4)) Then

// this sorts the last column

Temp4 = Array(index2, 4)
Array(index2, 4) = Array(index2 + 1, 4) 
Array(index2 + 1, 4) = Temp4

// and we repeat this swopping pattern for each of the other columns, so they are all sorted in the same way

Temp3 = Array(index2, 3)
Array(index2, 3) = Array(index2 + 1, 3) 
Array(index2 + 1, 3) = Temp3

Temp2 = Array(index2, 2)
Array(index2, 2) = Array(index2 + 1, 2) 
Array(index2 + 1, 2) = Temp2

Temp1 = Array(index2, 1)
Array(index2, 1) = Array(index2 + 1, 1) 
Array(index2 + 1, 1) = Temp1

Temp0 = Array(index2, 0)
Array(index2, 0) = Array(index2 + 1, 0) 
Array(index2 + 1, 0) = Temp0

Next
Next
```

All I have done is to convert the Datatype to the last column from String to Single, then compare the adjacent values as before.

So this is a very basic way of sorting a multidimensional array, and it works for mixed arrays containing strings and numbers as well.